# Не удается разделить ячейки таблицы CSS по ширине поровну

Tags: html, css, table, display

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться!

Дано:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 17rem;
}

.block__item {
  background-color: aqua;
  /*width: 200px;*/
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block__item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.block__item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.block-1 {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.block-1 .block__item {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: solid #fff 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block block-1">
    <div class="block__item"></div>
    <div class="block__item"></div>
    <div class="block__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну, и три дива.

Вопрос: почему ширины этих дивов не делятся поровну? 
Почему их разбивает на 447, 446 и 446 при ширине родителя 1339px?
Как сделать так, чтобы ширина была: 
446,333333 у каждой ячейки, то есть, ровно одна треть?
Благодарю.

Вот код:
[ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/iliyasold/pen/mdbQXXe)

Comment: так делится все поровну

Comment: 447 446 446 - так делиться же? Почему с grid, например, делиться, как 446,3333 каждый, а здесь нет? Или - это в принципе не возможно с table сделать?

Comment: у вас ширина 33% округляет браузер сам. Если хотите точно то нужна js функция которая при загрузке или ресайзе будет делить и писать инлайново

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Другими словами, без применения дополнительных сил это сделать не возможно!)

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items{     
  overflow: hidden;  
  font-size: 0;  
}
.item{  
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100vh;  
  width: calc(100%/3);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;  
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.item:nth-of-type(even){
  background: #ddd;
}
.item:after{
  content: 'text design';
  position: absolute; bottom: 5%; left: 5%;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;  
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Добрый день!
Всё так, но я хочу понять поведение именно при display: table;

Comment: Почему при width: calc(100% / 3); на детях ничего не происходит в этом случае, грубо говоря, блоки вообще не реагируют на то: указана ширина или нет? Почему при display: table; у родителя, блоки тупо бьются "по модулю" без долей? Чем обусловлено такое поведение? Как его поменять?